# ionic 3 with AdmobFree : ion-tabs disappears after closing share to email modal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native, cordova-admob, ionic-tabs

I am developing ionic(version:3.20.0) ios app and added Ad Banner using Admob Free plugin (cordova-plugin-admob-free 0.13.0) at the bottom. I have set the  overlap:false.

It shows the Ad Banner at the bottom of Footer Tabs(ion-tabs) which is correct. But when after I share a content (a text for example) from the app to Email, and close the share window the footer tabs disappears and only shows the Ad Banner. Could anybody help me to fix this issue please. I think the ion-tabs goes behind the Ad Banner.

Or Is there any way to set the bottom position of ion-tabs to a fixed value so that I can leave some space at bottom of tabs for the Adbanner.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same problem for a long time, on iOS only.  Android seems to work fine.

Would be really grateful for a solution.